# Can not convert javascript object to json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

After I create a javascript object and convert it to json my object is not fully converted.

Create javascript object.

```
var inputData = {
    "StartDate": moment(startDate).format('YYYY[-]MM[-]DD'),
    "EndDate": moment(endDate).format('YYYY[-]MM[-]DD'),
    "AllRates": []
};
```

Fill array with objects received from API.

```
for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
    $.getJSON(
        "http://api.fixer.io/" + dates[i] + "?base=USD", 
        function (data) {
            inputData.AllRates.push(data);
        }
    );
}
```

I get an object that looks like this:
[console.log(inputData);](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2S6N.png)

But when I convert an object into json by JSON.stringify() I get an empty array:

```
{"StartDate":"2017-07-10","EndDate":"2017-07-13","AllRates":[]}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably converting the object to JSON before the data from the requests arrived and your `inputData.AllRates.push(data)` callback got called. You have to keep track how many responses arrived and convert to JSON only after the last one arrived:

```
var dateCount = dates.length;
var finished = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < dateCount; i++){
  $.getJSON("http://api.fixer.io/" + dates[i] + "?base=USD", 
    function(data){
      inputData.AllRates.push(data);
      if(++finished === dateCount){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(inputData));
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: You'd still want to do something after retrieval completion (besides logging), so I would look into [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) ^^

Comment: You could still call a custom callback instead of just logging. I would definitely use `Promise.all` if the AJAX function would return a Promise (or if using for example the fetch API instead), but in that situation I am not sure if it wouldn't get more complex by partly using promises.

Comment: Thank you, this solution works)
But  the JSON.stringify(inputData) is called after the loop and the data from API was inside the object, which means inputData.AllRates.push(data) callback got called?

Comment: `inputData.AllRates.push` runs every time a response arrives, `JSON.stringify` only when the last one arrives and thus all rates have been stored already.